# Editor не обновляет информацию

Tags: android, cursor

Мне нужно, что-бы editor обновлял информацию. Но, видимо, сам editor срабатывает только 1 раз. Даже если я в другом классе очищу editor от любой информации, он все равно не обновляется

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        Calendar x = Calendar.getInstance();
        int y = x.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int m = x.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int d = x.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int h = x.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min = x.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int s = x.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        db.open();
        cursor = db.getAllData();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("txt"));
                int d110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("day"));
                int m110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("month"));
                int y110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("year"));
                int h120 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("hour"));
                int min120 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("minute"));
                if (d110 == d && m110 == m && h120 == h && min120 == min) 
                {
                    i = y - y110;
                    SharedPreferences ui;
                    ui = getSharedPreferences("Q", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ui.edit();
                    editor.putInt("age",i);
                    editor.putString("name",name);
                    editor.commit();
                    not();
                }
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());//takes next item
            cursor.close();

            handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Выведите в логи инфу о заходе в блоки хода, выясните какие и в каком порядке выполняются. Так вы сможете локализовать проблему. На первый взгляд ошибок не видно.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
private static boolean canWork = true;

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

      while(canWork) { 

        Calendar x = Calendar.getInstance();
        int y = x.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int m = x.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int d = x.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int h = x.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min = x.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int s = x.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        db.open();
        cursor = db.getAllData();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("txt"));
                int d110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("day"));
                int m110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("month"));
                int y110 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("year"));
                int h120 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("hour"));
                int min120 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("minute"));
                if (d110 == d && m110 == m && h120 == h && min120 == min) 
                {
                    i = y - y110;
                    SharedPreferences ui;
                    ui = getSharedPreferences("Q", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ui.edit();
                    editor.putInt("age",i);
                    editor.putString("name",name);
                    editor.commit();
                    not();
                }
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());//takes next item
            cursor.close();

            // handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
            // Вместо этого
            try {
              Thread.sleep(30000);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
      }
    };
```